# Select input from form - changes every submit

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

Add image of the html. I'm not able to copy multiple lines in inspect element for some reason
[image]

I'm trying to fill the input of this form

```html
 <div class="field" xpath="1"><label class="label">E-Mail *</label> <div class="control is-clearfix"><input type="text" autocomplete="on" class="input"> <!----> <!----> <!----></div> <!----></div>
```

My current xpath

```
"/html/body/div[5]/div[@class='animation-content modal-content']/div/section//section[@class='tab-content']/div[2]/div[1]/div/input[@type='text']"
```

The problem is the xpath I'm using changes every submission so I can only submit once. If someone can provide a xpath that doesn't change every submission I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi, Can you provide some more information like a link and what you are trying to click?

Comment: pls provide link to website. You have you create more specific XPATH using class or id.

Comment: @DurgaPrasadBehera  added image of the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the information you provided, you can Try to use this xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class, "field")]//input[@class="input"]
```

to find name:

```
//label[contains(text(), "Name")]/following-sibling::div//input[@class="input"]
```

email:

```
//label[contains(text(), "E-Mail")]/following-sibling::div//input[@class="input"]
```

phone:

```
//label[contains(text(), "Phone")]/following-sibling::div//input[@class="input"]
```

Comment: Added image of the html. Wouldn't just input get other fields as well?

Comment: It finds 3 inputs for `Name`, `Email` and `Phone`

Comment: Is there a way to categorize them individually?

Comment: yes, you can use this to find name ```//label[contains(text(), "Name")]/following-sibling::div//input[@class="input"]```

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath added by the Roman is satisfactory for your needs it just you need to understand how you can improve your Xpath there are multiple ways to do it ,

I will add some more Xpath so that it will be helpful in the near future.

1. I personally prefer the below mentioned way of writing the Xpath

```
//label[contains(text(), "Name")]/following-sibling::div//input[@class="input"]
```

But there are some other ways to I will add one of the Xpath from my project where you can also learn how we use the parent and following-sibling

```
//label[contains(text(),'PlantCode*')]//parent::div[@class='rb_Work_FieldContainer']//following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'rb_Work_FieldValueArea rb_Work_FieldValueArea_create ')]//textarea[@class='textarea']
```

These are some of the ways to find the Xpath, You can also use the extension like chropath in the Chrome to help you out in building the Xpath,

Comment: Unforunately Chropath doesn't produce Xpath like that. It sometimes work, sometimes doesn't